# su vs su - (on Debian): why is PATH the same?

Tags: shell, command-line, su

I know what should be the difference between `su` and `su -`, but in my system (Debian) for example `PATH` is the same:

```
[root]# su
[root]# echo $PATH
/user_path/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[root]# exit
[root]$ su -
[root@debian ~]# echo $PATH
/user_path/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

So I'm starting to think that the settings can be changed in configuration files.

Comment: Please see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7013/why-do-we-use-su-and-not-just-su

Comment: They're the same because the path for your normal user is already the same as that for root.

Comment: What distribution/operating system?  The exact answer depends, for example the defaults are different for Red Hat/Fedora and Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that Debian people have changed the `su` program since this question was written and answered.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/460478/5132

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For configuring the `su` `PATH`, have a look at `/etc/login.defs`:

```
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

There are also a number of other places `PATH` can be changed, including:

- `/etc/environment`
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/profile.d/*`
- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.bash_profile`

Without anything special in per-user settings, `su` seems to be getting its `PATH` from `/etc/environment` and `su -` seems to be getting its environment from `/etc/login.defs` `ENV_SUPATH`.

So on your system, my guess is that you have the same `PATH` value in `/etc/login.defs` as in `/etc/environment`, or you have some extra configuration in `/etc/profile.d`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, or some rc file in `/home/someuser`.

Answer (score 4):

Parameter `-` means starting environment which is almost the same as with login environment for that user.

Without `-` environment is same as original user's environment.

For example `PATH` is usually same for root and normal users. In some systems there is no `sbin` folders for normal users. You can't disable `-` from `su` easily. Of course you can go to edit the source code.

You can try this by running

```
export FOO=bar
su # enter your password
echo $FOO
logout
su - # enter your password again
echo $FOO
```

In first time `echo $FOO` prints "bar" and in second time it's empty.