# debian su - and su $PATH differences?

Tags: bash, debian, root, su

```
$ su -
Password: 
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# exit
logout
$ su
Password: 
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I have no idea why /bin and /sbin are not added to `$PATH`, if I do the plain su. This used to be the case. How can I fix this? I did notice that:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  8  2018 /etc/environment
```

But otherwise my system seems normal.

EDIT: I forgot the obligatory `uname -a`

```
Linux rpi3 4.17.0-1-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 4.17.8-1 (2018-07-20) aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

EDIT2:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid \n \l
```

all of the packages are from the "testing" repo, since "stable" ones don't work very well on aarch64.

Comment: I see `/bin` in both of your examples. you you say “I have no idea why /bin … are not added to $PATH”

Comment: Considering your kernel, that means you're not using only Debian stable. YOu absolutely have to add the result of this command: `dpkg -S $(which su)` and dpkg -l *packagefromresult* to know its version

Comment: Also please state if using stretch/stable, buster/testing or sid/unstable overall

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Very recently (with version 2.32-0.2 of `util-linux` from 27 Jul 2018) Debian switched to a different `su` implementation, see [bug 833256](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=833256). The "new" `su` is from `util-linux` while the "old" one was contained in the `login` package and originated from `src:shadow`

Quoting from [`util-linux/NEWS.Debian.gz`](https://sources.debian.org/src/util-linux/2.33.1-0.1/debian/util-linux.NEWS/):

> The two implementations are very similar but have some minor differences (and there might be more that was not yet noticed ofcourse), e.g.
>
> - new 'su' (with no args, i.e. when preserving the environment) also preserves PATH and IFS, while old su would always reset PATH and IFS even in 'preserve environment' mode.
> - su '' (empty user string) used to give root, but now returns an error.
> - previously su only had one pam config, but now 'su -' is configured separately in /etc/pam.d/su-l
>
> The first difference is probably the most user visible one. Doing plain 'su' is a really bad idea for many reasons, so using 'su -' is strongly recommended to always get a newly set up environment similar to a normal login. If you want to restore behaviour more similar to the previous one you can add 'ALWAYS_SET_PATH yes' in /etc/login.defs.

The previously used `su` implementation behaved differently regarding `PATH`. This is also discussed in this bug report, see [833256#80](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=833256#80). The new `su` preserves `PATH` if *not* invoked with `su -`.

In short: Debian's old `su` behaved like `su -`, at least regarding `PATH`. With the new implementation you should almost always use `su -`, similar to other distributions.

Comment: Considering the OP added: `4.17.0-1-arm64` as kernel, OP should really state the precise Debian version used and the precise package providing `/bin/su`, because with this kernel it appears the util-linux implementation might be in use (thus making my answer less useful)

Comment: Isaac: True, however I never stated that this is the current default.

@A.B: Also true. Kernel 4.17 is currently only used in testing (upcoming release "buster" aka Debian 10) and unstable, both are currently very close to each other.

Comment: @scai I use testing as it is the only repo I could get to work with aarch64 on a raspberry pi 3.

Comment: It might be also useful to note that the new `su` will read `PATH` env var from `/etc/environment` overriding anything set in `etc/login.defs`. Took me a while to find it ...

Answer (score 2):

The Debian [`su` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/login/su.1.en.html) tells:

> The current environment is passed to the new shell. The value of `$PATH`
>   is reset to `/bin:/usr/bin` for normal users, or
>   `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` for the superuser. This may be changed
>   with the `ENV_PATH` and `ENV_SUPATH` definitions in `/etc/login.defs`.

Quoting from `/etc/login.defs`:

> ```
> # Three items must be defined:  MAIL_DIR, ENV_SUPATH, and ENV_PATH.
> # If unspecified, some arbitrary (and possibly incorrect) value will
> # be assumed.  All other items are optional - if not specified then
> ```

On a normal Debian system the variables are defined in`/etc/login.defs` :

```
#
# *REQUIRED*  The default PATH settings, for superuser and normal users.
#
# (they are minimal, add the rest in the shell startup files)
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Testing by commenting out `ENV_SUPATH` reproduces partially your problem: `su` will not have `/sbin` (nor `/usr/local/bin`) while `su -` will execute the login script `/etc/profile` which will redefine `PATH` as expected for the root user.

So you should check for any alteration of `/etc/login.defs` and correct it, or see if an other part alters the `PATH` later (like a shell startup script such as some non-login bashrc script)

Comment: my ENV_SUPATH is exactly as you present it, but plain `su` produces $PATH `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Comment: that probably means you're in the second case: a global bashrc script (or any other unsuspected script) doesn't check for uid 0 before choosing PATH (like the id -u -eq 0 check done in `/etc/profile` for the `su -` case). If you suspect something special done recently on your system you should add it in the question.

Comment: it's very puzzling to me, that's why I asked the question. I see the check for uid 0 in /etc/profile, but still there is the abnormal $PATH

Comment: I'd run a quite wide `inotifywait -r -m /etc /root /home/myuser > /tmp/list` (or wider) , run `su` and look for a suspect in the results from `/tmp/list`. Also check selinux/apparmor if you're not using `su` from a normal shell

Comment: note: `/etc/profile` isn't used with `su`, only with `su -`. That was just an example.