# Setting the root PATH for su

Tags: environment-variables, root, path, su

When I am changing (on my debian box) to the root user with `su`, apparently the PATH is not correctly set. Some vital directories like `usr/local/sbin` are missing.

In `/etc/profile` I have the following lines (apparently standard default stuff not written by me):

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0]; then
    PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin/:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
    PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
fi
export PATH
```

In `/etc/login.defs` I have (also default stuff):

```
ENV_SUPATH PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Why is my PATH not correctly set when I do `su`?

Comment: Are you running "su" or running "su -". ALWAYS use "su -", never use "su" you miss a load of config.

Comment: @Owl Wo, I didn't know that. Extremely useful, thanks. For those who wants to know more: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7013/101324

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modern `su` no longer resets `PATH` from the caller when asked to preserve the environment; if you need this to happen execute `su --login` instead.

From `/usr/share/doc/util-linux/NEWS.Debian.gz`:

```
- new 'su' (with no args, i.e. when preserving the environment) also
  preserves PATH and IFS, while old su would always reset PATH and IFS
  even in 'preserve environment' mode.
...
The first difference is probably the most user visible one. Doing
plain 'su' is a really bad idea for many reasons, so using 'su -' is
strongly recommended to always get a newly set up environment similar
to a normal login. If you want to restore behaviour more similar to
the previous one you can add 'ALWAYS_SET_PATH yes' in /etc/login.defs.
```

Comment: I've just now been bitten by this, after upgrading to _debian Buster_. This was super helpful.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/460478/5132 .