# Why doesn't "usermod" work under superuser?

Tags: sudo, su, usermod

The `usermod` command successfully through sudo.

```
sudo usermod -aG some_group some_user
```

However, if you execute it through su, then there will be an error.

```
su
...I enter root password...
usermod -aG some_group some_user
bash: usermod: command not found
```

Why it happens?

How to configure my system?

The fact is that I have a script that I cannot change.
This script uses command usermod under su.

Comment: Try providing the full path to `usermod`.

Comment: You might be suffering from https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/460478/117549

Comment: Thanks friends. That helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su` loads profile from /etc/profile which may modifies shell `$PATH` variable.

`man su` says

```
-m, -p, --preserve-environment
              Preserve the entire environment, i.e., it does not set HOME,
              SHELL, USER nor LOGNAME.  This option is ignored if the option
              --login is specified.
```

so, use `--preserve-environment` flag to load `$PATH` from existing shell

```
su --preserve-environment
```

OR
manually export PATH variable

```
su
export PATH=$PATH:/path/of/usermod/dir
```

Answer (score 5):

You need the `$PATH` setting for `root`. That is no problem with `sudo` because it has its own `$PATH`.

`su` does not change `$PATH` by default. You have to make it start a login shell:

```
su -
```

instead of just

```
su
```

If you cannot change the `su` call then change `$PATH` before the call. If `usermod` is located at `/usr/sbin/usermod` then do this:

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH
su
```