# Debian 10 su command to existing user as root without password

Tags: debian, security, password, su

I just installed a brand new VM with Debian 10 (buster) and joined it to our active directory using `pbis`.

what I encountered now is, that:

- as the root user, I can `su` to every other available user in our AD
  WITHOUT being asked for a password
- as a normal user I can
  only `su` to other users if I have the correct password and type it in

In previous versions of Debian (like 9) it was not possible do do that.

What I did to join the AD:

```
apt install gnupg -y
wget -O - http://repo.pbis.beyondtrust.com/apt/RPM-GPG-KEY-pbis | apt-key add 
wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pbiso.list http://repo.pbis.beyondtrust.com/apt/pbiso.list
apt-get update
apt-get install pbis-open -y
pbis join full.domain.name.de $ADMINUSER $ADMINPW
pbis set-default-domain full.domain.name.de
/opt/pbis/bin/config UserDomainPrefix PREFIX
/opt/pbis/bin/config AssumeDefaultDomain true
/opt/pbis/bin/config LoginShellTemplate "/bin/bash"
/opt/pbis/bin/config RequireMembershipOf "PREFIX\\admingoup" "PREFIX\\${HOST}-admin" "PREFIX\\${HOST}-user"
/opt/pbis/bin/config HomeDirTemplate "%H/%U"
sed -i '23a%admingroup ALL=(ALL) ALL' /etc/sudoers
sed -i '23a%'${HOST}'-admin ALL=(ALL) ALL' /etc/sudoers
```

so the other settings are basically standard. This is driving me crazy and I can't find out where to look what has changed since Debian 9 to the `su` command.

edit:
so basically I become root with
`sudo su`and then go for `su other.user` and it just works without a password prompt.

If I'm a non root user e.g. "normal.user" and go for `su other.user` it asks for the password and only lets me do it if I type in the correct one.

Comment: Are you in the `admingroup`?

Comment: @AndyDalton yes, but this should not affect anything, because the problem only occurs when I'm aleady root and try to su to another user - NOT when I'm logged in as a normal admin that has the right to become root, but isn't at the time I try to use ```su other.user``` - so ```admin.user@vmname: su other.user```gives me the password prompt for other.user, ```root@vmname: su other.user```doesnt and just continues to ```other.user@vmname:```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't find out where to look what has changed since Debian 9 to the `su` command.

You look at `packages.debian.org`.

- [In Debian 9](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stretch&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=su) the `su` command was provided by [the shadow package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/shadow).
- [In Debian 10](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=buster&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=su) the `su` command was provided by [the util-linux package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/util-linux).

There are differences caused by this switch. 
 "[debian su - and su $PATH differences?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/460478/5132)" shows one such difference.  "[su vs su - (on Debian): why is PATH the same?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7911/5132)" is a question here whose answers have been invalidated by the change.

There were also several problems as a consequence, including that initially the util-linux package did not install the right PAM configurations for `su`.
The NEWS file for util-linux also mentions that the util-linux `su` has multiple PAM configurations, not just one.
Your BeyondTrust package [installs PAM stuff in Debian](https://github.com/BeyondTrust/pbis-open/blob/b1ffc871065cb13fcdde0f60c522a80a658c607a/config/linux/debian/pbis.pam-auth-update).
Check that it is interoperable with the different `su` that Debian is now providing.

## Further reading

- Laurent Bigonville (2016-08-02). *[Please use `login`/`passwd` implementations provided by util-linux](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=833256#5)*.  Debian Bug #833256.
- Alf Gaida (2018-07-28). *[Have a working `su` again](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=904832#5)*.  Debian Bug #904832.
- crazyworlds (2017-06-15).  *[Cannot change root password](https://github.com/BeyondTrust/pbis-open/issues/42)*. BeyondTrust Bug #42

Comment: thank you! nevertheless, I found out, that also debian 9 has these "issues" - Well, maybe the root power just explains it all: "With great power comes great responsibility".