# Can I change root password by sudo, without su?

Tags: sudo, password

I can sudo, but I don't have the root password so I can't `su root`. Using sudo, can I change the root password?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So you want to run something like `sudo passwd root`?

Answer (score 18):

You can also just use

```
sudo su
```

and keep the root account without password.

Comment: Once I understood I can do this, I did "passwd -d root". Thanks!

Comment: But why was my answer downgraded after having been accepted ?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
sudo passwd
```

Note that you also want to log in using `su -` instead of `su` ([more info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7013/688)).

Answer (score 4):

If you have your sudo password then try the following (this is on Ubuntu 14.04LTS):

```
ewan@user-sbc-ihsw:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for ewan: 
root@user-sbc-ihsw:~# passwd
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
root@user-sbc-ihsw:~# whoami
root
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use sudo with the "-i" option. this will log you in as root without using the su command.

`sudo -i`

Answer (score 1):

You can change all these options in sudoers file, even make no password if you want( I would not recommend this though).