# dpkg cannot find ldconfig/start-stop-daemon in the PATH variable

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg, mailx

I was trying to install `bsd-mailx` utility the package got installed however I am wondering about the error.

This is the error I get:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of echo `$PATH` please?

Comment: @chaos,How to get that?

Comment: @user87142 Just type `echo $PATH` in a terminal.

Comment: @chaos,I get this .../usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: And the output of `cat /etc/environment`?

Comment: @chaos,I get this...PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Comment: @user87142 somewhere (maybe in the rc scripts of bash) your $PATH variable is truncated. It could be everywhere. post the output of the following command. Maybe there is a hint: `grep -P 'PATH=' ~/.bash* ~/.profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/bash_completion.d/* /etc/*`

Comment: How do you elevate privileges to root?

Answer (score 78):

First of all, the lines you are truly interested in are:

```
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable.
```

These errors have been reported several times by Debian and Ubuntu users (you can actually Google them for more information). It seems like the `PATH` variable isn't correctly set when the user tries to execute a command through `sudo`, which is probably what you are trying to do.

### Solution 1: Set `sudo`'s default secure path

Open `/etc/sudoers` by running `visudo` in your terminal, and make sure the file includes the following line:

```
Defaults env_reset
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

More information about this problem may be found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo) (Problems and tips > PATH not set).

### Solution 2: use the root account directly

Don't use `sudo`, just switch to `root` to run your commands. Run one of the following commands to do so:

```
$ sudo -i
$ su
```

Once you are logged in as root, just run your `apt-get` commands again:

```
# apt-get ...
```

You might have to set root's `PATH` first though. Edit `/root/.bashrc` (with root privileges of course), and add the following line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

### Solution 3: try to pass the `PATH` variable to `sudo` at execution time.

Just prefix the `sudo` call with the redefinition of the `PATH` variable:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin sudo apt-get ...
```

Comment: I have tried using root user but didn't work.I have checked path too.

Comment: @user87142 Well you didn't check correctly, since `/sbin` is missing. Try setting it up again (solutions 1 and/or 3). I edited solution 2 to include a way to edit root's PATH when using the account interactively.

Comment: I have checked that......Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

Comment: Did you find any solution of it?

Comment: A variation of his 3rd solution is to `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin` first, then `sudo -E apt install nginx` after that.  The `-E` switch means `--preserve-env` thus exporting your env vars to the `sudo` session.

Comment: An alternative if your root account doesn't have it in Debian, use `su -` to add sbin to the PATH. `su` will NOT have these folders in the PATH by default, and the spash dash after is required to add them in. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918754

Answer (score 11):

somehow I had the same problem.

Please read your error message carefully and you will find the solution.
There is a note that says:

> Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin
>   and /sbin.

Then I checked my path and somehow I was missing the /sbin in my path.

> echo $PATH

then I added and the problem was gone. :)

> export PATH="$PATH:/sbin"

Tcharam!

Comment: Pretty sure this has already been covered by [an existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160021/117549), though

Answer (score 7):

The lack of description in the question makes it hard to pinpoint the exact problem in this situation, but I recently faced the same issue:

```
user@debian:su
Password: 
root@debian:/home/user/Downloads# dpkg -i [Some package]
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

The solution was to use `su -` instead of `su` (which is generally better, as detailed in [the answers to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7013/101324)):

```
user@debian:su -
Password: 
root@debian:~# cd /home/user/Downloads/
root@debian:/home/user/Downloads# dpkg -i [Some package]
```

Comment: Great, worked for me! I still have a habit to write `su root`

Comment: @dompie I'm sticking to `su -` since, and prefer it. It's a bit tricky to get used to it, but it's definitely better on the long run, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today, and solved it by commenting out the line (using a #)

```
Defaults    exempt_group=sudo
```

from my /etc/sudoers file using

```
# visudo
```

as root

This change will cause sudo to use the default secure_path variable set in the same file.

Comment: This resolved it for me on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions showed here helped me, so I'll explain what happened to me and what I did to fix it:

I was trying to install Insync in my Q4OS System and I wasn't able because the app requires libc6 >= 2.32 and the Q4OS uses 2.31. I found a libc6 deb of 2.32 and then the nightmare started. It has been broken my entire system. `apt-get` stopped to work and it says the system needs libc6 2.31 to work properly. At that time I didn't know how to downgrade the version. So, after a restart, the system simply didn't start and hung up with the message on boot:

```
A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)
```

I tried to change the terminal without success. Hopefully my Linux was running under the VMWare and I was able to connect in the machine using the SSH. `VM -> SSH -> Connect to SSH...`

After that, I tried a lot of stuff without success. I tried to upgrade with:

```
sudo apt install upgrade
```

and the message says I had to run:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

But when I tried to run that, it said a lot of packages would be removed, including `q4os-desktop` itself. Well, I accept the conditions and tried. What more could I lost?

After that, the thing gets too worse. I wasn't able to run anything. I got a similar error of the question:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

But the problem wasn't the PATH itself but the ldconfig is part of libc6 and it was removed. I couldn't do anything because almost everything depends of libc6 and ldconfig. I tried to compile libc6 from source, but without success. It has a lot of dependencies and when I tried to install a dependency, the lib tried to use something of libc6. A kind of dependency loop.

So, I reboot the system with the Q4OS live CD and just copy the binary ldconfig to `/usr/sbin/ldconfig`. Fine! Now, the `apt-get` started to work again (not perfectly, but...). So I discovered how to downgrade the lib:

```
sudo apt install libc6=2.31-13+deb11u3
```

If you are not sure which version to use, run:

```
apt list --installed | grep libc6
```

inside the Live CD. The output should be something like:

```
libc6/stable,now 2.31-13+deb11u3 amd64 [installed]
```

After that, I was able to install the Q4OS again:

```
sudo apt install q4os-desktop
```

After a reboot, everything was back to normal!

But now when I run the Insync, the app crashes after 5 seconds.