# User Lastlog login datetime did not update

Tags: linux, rhel, users, last, wtmp

I use `lastlog` to check latest login datetime. Here are steps I use to update my latest login datetime.

1) Try to Login to that user

> sudo su userA

2) Exit that user and login to `root` then check latest login datetime

> lastlog -u userA

3) But the result is not updated and will be

> "**Never logged in**"

Can I know the root cause here or the solution how to update it? I usually try this way and can update other `users`.

Comment: Root "becoming" userA does not mean userA logged in. The login process wasn't involved. You could try "su - userA" but I'm not sure.

Comment: It might be because you're using 'su' (without the hyphen). [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7013/why-do-we-use-su-and-not-just-su) claims that 'su -' creates a login shell whereas the other does not.