# Xauthority for python plotting in a docker container

Tags: x11, python, docker, display, xauth

I'm trying to understand how to run a docker container with an X11 server running in it so that I can do visualizations when I write some python code, and found lots of answers out there.

I found many questions and many answers, but even though some provide a solution most have a subpar explanation for a newbie like myself. So I am not able to get it to work in my specific case.

So could someone please help me understand why is this not working?

```
$> XSOCK=/tmp/.X11-unix
$> XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth
$> xauth nlist $DISPLAY | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -
$> sudo docker run --name my_name \
                 -v $XSOCK:$XSOCK \
                 -v $XAUTH:$XAUTH \
                 -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
                 -e XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH \
                 -it b9d09a81e708
```

Here is the error I get when I try to create a figure with `matplotlib`:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [2]: plt.figure()
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

...

TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:10.0"
```

Here is my current understanding regarding this sequence of commands:

1. Connect the existing X11 socket on the local machine to the one in the docker container by creating a new variable `XSOCK` containing the path of the socket on the local machine and mounting it with the `-v` flag.
2. Create a new socket at `/tmp/.docker.xauth` (this file does not exist currently) by creating a new variable `XAUTH` containing the path of the socket on the local machine and mounting it with the `-v` flag.
3. Use [`xauth`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xauth.1.html) command to list the current displays on the local machine (in numeric format), change them using the `sed` command, and then add them back to the new socket file just created.
4. Run the docker image and create new variables `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` that have the value of `DISPLAY` and `XAUTH` on the local machine.

Here is are things that still escape me:

1. What is the newly created socket `/tmp/.docker.xauth` used for?
2. What does the command `xauth nlist $DISPLAY | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -` do? In particular:

   a. what is the `sed` portion used for, and how is it changing the output of `xauth nlist $DISPLAY` as an input to `xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -`?

   b. what is the `-` at the end of `xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -`?
3. Can any of these commands be done directly inside of the Dockerfile so that there isn't all this overhead in connecting to it?

Thanks

Comment: for 2.b: that particular command's "-" refers to STDIN (if excepting input) or STDOUT (if expecting to output). for ex: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xauth : `%  xauth extract - $DISPLAY | rsh otherhost xauth merge -` (the xauth extract uses "-" to mean "output the extraction to STDOUT", and after the pipe the xauth merge uses "-" to mean "merge from STDIN") .  And 2.a : that sed changes the first 4 chars into "ffff"  (ie, whatever those 4 first chars were, they now are 'ffff')

Comment: your DISPLAY seems to be set to : localhost:10. You may want to check your (well, localhost's) Xserver logs to check if this is the proper display it is attached to. you may want to test a simple xclock display on it :   DISPLAY="localhost:10" xclock   # should open a simple clock on that Xserver. then press ctrl-C to close it.
If it says it can't open it, it may be because $DISPLAY is not set correctly, or the Xserver is not running properly, or .... check logs ^^