# Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N 6205 not found in Debian

Tags: debian, wifi

I was installing Debian. But, I know that I have installed wireless connection system manually in Debian.

[image]

But, I couldn't install wireless connection while installing Debian. I had connected Ethernet although, I couldn't install it. So, I had skipped it. I downloaded `iwlwifi-6000g2a-ucode-18.168.6.1.tgz` from [Intel Wireless connection](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html). I had tried to some commands also

```bsh
apt-get install linux-firmware
apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
```

Both had returned "unable to locate package". When I had extracted `wlwifi-6000g2a-ucode-18.168.6.1.tgz`, I just found three files. I don't think that I can do something with them. So, how can I install wireless network in Debian.

[image]

I had made changes to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.10.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20210619-16:11]/ buster main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.10.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20210619-16:11]/ buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free


deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

```
root@Istiak:/home/istiak# lspci | grep -i network
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

I don't have modprobe also.

Comment: `firmware-iwlwifi` https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-iwlwifi ........ Please enable the `non-free` repo. ....https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=firmware-iwlwifi

Comment: @KnudLarsen Please! check my question. I had added that..

Comment: @KnudLarsen Anyway, I have installed it.

Comment: Confirm : add "contrib non-free" to deb lines in sources.list : Then no issues .... all firmware installs OK.

Comment: @KnudLarsen But, I wonder I don't have `modprobe` in system. Even, I can't install it. Why?

Comment: Was it with Debian 9 that su changed ? ... You now have to do `su -` to use most root commands, including  `modprobe` command and `apt install [package]`    .https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7013/why-do-we-use-su-and-not-just-su

Comment: @KnudLarsen gotcha :)

Answer (score 1):

I had mentioned in [the comment](https://linux.codidact.com/comments/thread/3384#comment-11119),

> @Canina‭ I had updated my system also.

But, actually I had updated my system before making changes to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

---

At first, you have make some changes to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. You have to add following line to every line which starts with `deb` (in `/etc/apt/sources`).

```bsh
contrib non-free
```

Then, you have to update your system.

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Then, install `firmware-iwlwifi`. (Your default user won't be sudoers, that's why you have to work as a root user `su`)

```
apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
```

Then, you will have to reboot your PC.